# What HTML can be used to facilitate copying from browser and pasting to spreasheet across multiple cells

Tags: html, tabs, html-table, spreadsheet, html-entities

I need to generate HTML for text on a page that, when viewed in a browser, can be copied and pasted into a spreadsheet without having to copy cell by cell.

In a spreadsheet, tab characters can be used to separate cell contents, but HTML does not seem to support tab characters. For what it's worth, I have tried `&#09;`, `&nbsp;`, `&thinsp;`, `&ensp;`, and `&emsp;` with no success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I missed the obvious solution: Just put it in an html table. Table cells copy to spreadsheet cells.